# Using \pgftext in \behindbackground{} shape: color problems

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I do not know if this is expected or not; this is probably a very dumb operator error, but consider the following MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfdeclareshape{sline}{
    \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}%
    \behindbackgroundpath{
        % \pgfsetcolor{.}%       <- line B
        % \pgfsetfillcolor{red}% <- line A
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.3cm}{0pt}}%
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.3cm}{0pt}}%
        \pgfnode{circle}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}}%
        \pgftext[top,y=0.4cm]{zzz}%
        \pgfusepath{draw}%
    }
}
\begin{document}
Text
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw[] (0,1)  node [sline]{} (1,1) node{aaa};
    \draw[blue, fill=green] (0,0)  node [sline]{} (1,0) node{aaa};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which result in:

[image]

What is quite puzzling is the fact that "zzz" is following the *fill* color of the shape and not the *stroke* color. I tried to find something in the manual, to no avail.

What I would like is that the shape could follow the external "fill" parameter (either in the draw, or in the shape itself) *but* the text should follow the draw color, like "aaa" is doing (or at least following the external current color).

Uncommenting `line B` gives the "fill and stroke as the current color", as expected (`\pgfsetcolor` sets both stroke and fill):

[image]

...and uncommenting both line A and line B gives a fixed red fill *and* red text.

[image]

Commenting just line B gives:

[image]

In conclusion, it seems that the text created by `\pgftext` is colored with the fill color and colored with the current color only if the fill color is undefined. Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Both `\pgftext` and normal text are colored with the fill color. You can play with this pdf literal example: `\Huge text \pdfliteral page{q 2 Tr 1 0 0 rg 0 1 0 RG .5 w}text\pdfliteral page{Q} text`. Here `2 Tr` sets the rendering mode to "fill, then stroke text" (the default is fill only), `1 0 0 rg` sets the fill color red, and `0 1 0 RG` sets the stroke color green.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ thanks --- one always learns something new. So I suppose I will have to scope the `\pgftext` setting locally the color to the default one... is there something as `\pgf@textcolor` defined if the user says `node[blub, text=red]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- In principal, text is colored with fill color, not stroke color. After all, modern fonts are all outline fonts. Commands like `\color` and `\textcolor` set both the fill and stroke color, making the fact that "text is filled" less imperceptible.
- Therefore in pgf, each of `\pgftext`, `\pgfnode`, and `\pgfmultipartnode` colors the (node) text with current fill color.
- But tikz introduces a new concept "text color" which is set by `text=<color>` and init to empty per node. If set, for node text both the current fill and stroke color are locally set to the text color.  The [related code](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/b79c4c5c632110079c3827ce4963a27e6d5d1742/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex#L3896-L3900) is in `\tikz@do@fig`:

  ```tex
  \ifx\tikz@textcolor\pgfutil@empty%
  \else%
     \pgfutil@colorlet{.}{\tikz@textcolor}%
     \pgfutil@color{\tikz@textcolor}%
  \fi%
  ```

  A slightly different logic can be found in `\tikz@nodepart@continue` and `\tikz@fig@continue` which uses `\pgfsetcolor{.}` after `\fi` instead of `\pgfutil@color{\tikz@textcolor}`. The differences I know by far is that `\pgfsetcolor` will also set named colors `pgfstrokecolor` and `pgffillcolor`.
- Therefore, through tikz options, one can use up to three different colors for a node:

  ```tex
  \node[draw=blue, fill=yellow!20, text=cyan] {text};
  ```
- Back to pgf layer, some manual work is needed since option `text=<color>` is only available in tikz layer and the above code logic is only applied to tikz (not pgf) node text.

The example below provides a `\pgf@cir@usetextcolor` that sets the current fill and stroke color to text color if the latter is set.

```tex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{sline}{
    \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}%
    \behindbackgroundpath{
        % \pgfsetcolor{.}%       <- line B
        % \pgfsetfillcolor{red}% <- line A
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.3cm}{0pt}}%
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.3cm}{0pt}}%
        \pgfnode{circle}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}}%
        \pgfusepath{draw}
        % \pgfscope
        \pgf@circ@usetextcolor % if used at last, no need to wrap in pgfscope
        \pgftext[top,y=0.4cm]{zzz}%
        % \endpgfscope
    }
}

\def\pgf@circ@usetextcolor{%
  \ifx\tikz@textcolor\pgfutil@empty
  \else
    \pgfutil@colorlet{.}{\tikz@textcolor}%
    \pgfutil@color{\tikz@textcolor}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Text
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw[] (0,1)  node [sline]{} (1,1) node{aaa};
    \draw[blue, fill=green] (0,0)  node [sline]{} (1,0) node{aaa};
    \draw[blue, fill=green] (0,-1)  node [sline,text=red]{} (1,-1) node[text=red]{aaa};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Impressive answer +1

Comment: @SebGlav Hi, answer updated to correct some mistakes in explanation.

Comment: Thanks! In my case, it will be simpler because I do not really want the text in `\pgftext` to follow the text color, but the stroke color --- it's basically the numbering of pins or polarity, etc. so they are logically part of the shape "contour".