# Node text color not inherithed in xelatex (but inherited in pdflatex and lualatex)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, circuitikz

My last update to `circuitikz` popped up a strange thing that drove me crazy: if you look at [page 78 of the manual for 1.6.7](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/ebee38f423c7055098929a8b763a6cd8ff73a3ee/circuitikzmanualgit.pdf#59), you can see that the voltage source sign *does not* follow the color of the component. The strange thing is that they *do* it on my local build... so I was chasing strange bugs(*which can be still there...*) until I remembered that the CI scripts that build the release manual are using `xelatex` (for some historical reason, I think).

To check the problem, I managed to reduce the behavior to this MWE (which generates a couple of files and a script to obtain the final screenshot, if you are on a bash-compatible shell):

```latex
\begin{filecontents}{do_color_vam.sh}
pdflatex color-vam && mv color-vam.pdf color-vam-p.pdf
lualatex color-vam && mv color-vam.pdf color-vam-l.pdf
xelatex color-vam && mv color-vam.pdf color-vam-x.pdf
pdflatex color-vam-join
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{color-vam-join.tex}
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}
    \includegraphics{color-vam-p}\par
    \includegraphics{color-vam-l}\par
    \includegraphics{color-vam-x}\par
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{iftex}
\edef\engine{% just for the three cases tested...
    \ifluatex LuaLaTeX\else\ifxetex XeTeX \else pdfLaTeX\fi\fi
}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{foo}{
    \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}%
    \behindbackgroundpath{%
        \pgfscope
        \pgfpathellipse{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{0}{0.4cm}}{\pgfpoint{0.4cm}{0}}
        \pgfusepath{draw}
        %\ifxetex
        %    \pgftext[]{\let\current@color\pgf@fillcolor@global\set@color$+$}
        %\else
            \pgftext[]{$+$}
        %\fi
        \endpgfscope
    }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[color=red, thick]  node[foo]{} ++(1,0)
        node[foo, fill=blue]{} ++(1,0)
        node[right, text width=3cm]{\engine};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you run it once (with whichever engine, say `pdflatex`) and then run (on the shell)

```
sh ./do_color_vam
```

The file `color-vam-join.pdf` will look as follows:

[image]

As you can see, `xelatex` has a different behavior. Notice that the fact that the first two "plus" signs are blue is normal [because `\pgftext` uses the fill color](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/634867/using-pgftext-in-behindbackground-shape-color-problems#comment1582680_634867) to render the text (it also is normal that the circles are not filled up because I explicitly used only `draw` in the `\pgftext` command).

Ulrike Fischer (thanks!) [suggested in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/709273/node-text-color-not-inherithed-in-xelatex-but-inherited-in-pdflatex-and-lualate#comment1763952_709273) a possible solution, which I added (commented out) to the MWE: if you remove the comments and rerun, you will have:

[image]

which is arguably better for the default case, but [as Ulrike herself noticed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/709273/node-text-color-not-inherithed-in-xelatex-but-inherited-in-pdflatex-and-lualate#comment1763952_709273), it does not make the behavior the same for the three engines.

Is there some trick to make `xelatex` behave like the other two engines?

Comment: xetex (xdvipdfmx) has a tendency to inject more color resets than the other engines (somewhere (dvipdfmx list?) there is imho a discussion about that. So you would have to repeat a color setting. Something like `\pgftext[]{\ifxetex\let\current@color\pgf@fillcolor@global\set@color\fi $+$}` would work in your example, but break again if you use a color on your node `node[fill=green,foo]{}`. You are probably on another round of "figure out the color settings" https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/635242/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I *had* the sensation of deja-vu, yes... but this time, it seems engine-dependent... maybe I'll just add a warning in the manual, and then try to see if I can use an `\ifxetex` with some of the state I am trying to store after dealing with the other question you pointed to. Thanks!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I updated the question to make it more general and added your suggestion (also showing the fill thing you pointed to). I hope it's ok with you.

Comment: It would work, if you add `text=blue` as option (plus the `\ifxetex` stuff). But I wonder why that is ...

Comment: Found a similar open issue in the tikz repo: [pgf-tikz/pgf#750: With xelatex, \pgftext does not honor \pgfsetfillcolor](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/750).

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ that could be the answer... "it's a bug" ;-). Anyway, I would fix this and forget nesting tikzpictures --- color is probably the less important thing breaking in that case.